# kie-maven-plugin:7.36.1.Final Plugin extension dependency error using Maven

Tags: drools, maven-plugin, kie, maven-extension

**Migrating Drools from 6.5.0.Final to Drools 7.36.1.Final , I am facing issue in resolving org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.36.0.Final dependency issue as below**

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.36.0.Final or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.2.0, xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.2.0: Could not find artifact xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.2.0
```

POM entry

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.36.1.Final</version>
     <extensions>true</extensions>         
 </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi same problem with versions higher than 7.31.
Since they changed the dependencies in *kie-parent.pom*
from

```
<version.xmlpull>1.1.3.1</version.xmlpull>
<version.xmlunit>1.3</version.xmlunit>
<version.xpp3>1.1.4c</version.xpp3>
```

to

```
<version.xmlpull>1.2.0</version.xmlpull>
<version.xmlunit>1.3</version.xmlunit>
<version.xpp3>${version.xmlpull}</version.xpp3>
```

I try lot of tricks and can't solve the problem yet.
1.2.0 it's an ea version located in  https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/ea/.

Answer (score 0):

It can be found at: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xmlpull/xmlpull/1.2.0. I have no clue why it is not listed here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xmlpull/xmlpull so maven can resolve it.

you can download it and put it into your local m2 repository or into your company maven repository like nexus or artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one of those repo-s in your build, so maven can find it:

- https://mvnrepository.com/repos/jboss-ea
- https://mvnrepository.com/repos/jboss-thirdparty-releases